# How do I create a Sub-domain and Sub-folder in Azure?

Tags: azure, subdomain, subdirectory

I have a bitnami wordpress in Azure. 
I want to create a sub domain like subdomain.example.com.
I will install a new wordpress on this subdomain.
I want it on the same server.
I redirected my domain from Go Daddy to Azure. I have DNS Zone registration for example.com.

How is created subdomain in azure portal?
How can I creat folder for subdomain.example.com the same server?

(Note: Bitnami wordpress stack is available in server)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using App Service to host your sites.  When you create your first Web Site, you must create an App Service plan.  This plan can host multiple Web Sites so when you create your Web Sites, you simply need to select the previously created App Service plan.  For each new Web Site, you must edit the DNS entries in GoDaddy and set the correct subdomain in the Web Site settings like you did for the first site.